# Tikz / Making a node with $\cdots$ more prettier

Tags: tikz-pgf

Here is my code and the resultant diagram. I want the ellipse at both ends to be more smaller. How can I do this?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning, decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle{every node}=[inner sep=0mm, outer sep=0mm];
    \foreach \x/\y  in {1/1, 2/2, 3/1, 4/2, 5/1}
    \node[fill=black!30, circle] (m\x) at ({1.5*\x}, 0) {$m_{\y}$};

    \foreach \x in {1,2,3,4}
    \draw[decorate, decoration={coil,segment length=1.055mm}] (m\x) -- node[yshift=3mm] {$K$} (m\the\numexpr\x+1\relax);

    \draw[|<->|] ($ (m2) + (0, -0.4) $) -- node[below] {$d$} ($(m3) + (0, -0.4) $);
    \draw (m1) -- +(-0.4, 0) node[left] {$\tiny\cdots$} % how can i make it prettier?
    (m5) -- +(0.4,0) node[right] {$\tiny\cdots$}; % here too
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `node[left,scale=0.5]{$\tiny\cdots$}`?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. -- `\tiny` isn't recognized in math mode.  but `\scriptstyle` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"regular" font sizes aren't recognized in math mode, but there are equivalent "math sizes" -- `\scriptstyle` and `\scriptscriptstyle`.

this revision of your example changes three lines:

- the two lines where you used `\tiny`, replacing that with `\scriptstyle` and a   thin space on the appropriate side;
- removed the semicolon from the line beginning `\tikzstyle`, to get rid of an annoying error message.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning, decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle{every node}=[inner sep=0mm, outer sep=0mm]  %% <--
    \foreach \x/\y  in {1/1, 2/2, 3/1, 4/2, 5/1}
    \node[fill=black!30, circle] (m\x) at ({1.5*\x}, 0) {$m_{\y}$};

    \foreach \x in {1,2,3,4}
    \draw[decorate, decoration={coil,segment length=1.055mm}] (m\x) -- node[yshift=3mm] {$K$} (m\the\numexpr\x+1\relax);

    \draw[|<->|] ($ (m2) + (0, -0.4) $) -- node[below] {$d$} ($(m3) + (0, -0.4) $);
    \draw (m1) -- +(-0.4, 0) node[left] {$\scriptstyle\cdots\,$} %% <--
    (m5) -- +(0.4,0) node[right] {$\scriptstyle\.\cdots$}; %% <--
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]